# PHP: $var = $_GET not getting any value from select dropdown

Tags: php, mysqli, dropdown

i'm struggling on finding the reason why i can grab the $_GET (or $_POST) in my PHP code. I have a select dropdown populated from a table that works fine. The second part supposes to grab the selected value and use it in a second query but all i get is a blank page. I want to do it only using php.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","db","pwd");
mysqli_select_db($connect, "db");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Title </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET">
<Select name = "Paises">
<option selected disabled>Choose an option</option>
<?php
   $r = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT Pais from Brokers"); // Runing the query.
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) 
    {
?>
<option value =""><?php echo $row["Pais"];  ?>   </option>
<?php
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</select>
<?php 
  //Second part of code: Getting the selected value from dropdown menu named Paises
   $selected_pais = $_GET['Paises'];
   //using the value on second query:
   $r2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT BrokeryMercado from Brokers WHERE Pais = '".$selected_pais."'"); // Run the query.

   while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2)) {
   echo"{$row2['BrokeryMercado']}";

    // I get the same blank page when trying: echo "{$row2["BrokeryMercado"]}"; 
    //same result trying: echo "You have selected :" .$selected_pais; 
    }
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

It might be something stupid but I keep getting only a blank page. Tried 2 separates files and same results.
The url looks like this:  myfile.php?Paises=&submit=submit
So I guess there isn't getting any value there. 
Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: You have `<option value ="">` value empty.

Comment: Try this instead : <option value ="<?php echo $row["Pais"];  ?>  "> <?php echo $row["Pais"];  ?>  </option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused because you have an **empty** `'value' attribute` in your `option` tag and this can be the reason why `GET` or `POST` aren't getting anything.

```
<option value ="">
```

Try putting a value in it.

Ie, this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row["Pais"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["Pais"]; ?></option>
```

I hope it works, or at least `GET` or `POST` gives you something to test with.

Comment: You saved my day mate. I missed that. It's working now. 
That was fast and simple! I knew it was going to be a little thing lol 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, we make mistakes, we need eyes on everything. Make as resolved in that case.

Comment: Yeah, that happens. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the value attribute in option tag `<option value ="<?= $row["Pais"];  ?>"><?php echo $row["Pais"];  ?>   </option>`